# Select a range of column base on value of another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset looks like this(first row is header)

```
0    1    2    3    4    5
1    3    4    6    2    3
3    8    9    3    2    4
2    2    3    2    1    2
```

I want to select a range of columns of the dataset based on the column [5], e.g:

```
1    3    4
3    8    9    3
2    2
```

I have tried the following, but it did not work:

```
df.iloc[:,0:df['5'].values]
```

Comment: What kind of output you want? If it s a dataframe, do you want to replace missing values with nans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[:x.iloc[5]], 1)
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  3.0  4.0  NaN
1  3.0  8.0  9.0  3.0
2  2.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Nice one :-) I like the usage of `apply`

Comment: `apply` is  neater  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Recreate your dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame([x[:x[5]] for x in df.values]).fillna(0)
df
Out[184]: 
   0  1    2    3
0  1  3  4.0  0.0
1  3  8  9.0  3.0
2  2  2  0.0  0.0
```